# How to Auto deploy jar file using GIT

Tags: git, deployment

I have developed a pure java exit that is executed via a Third Party product.

The java exit code is held in GIT and I am using MAVEN to build a jar file.

I would like to have the jar file automatically deployed onto the remote server hosting the Third Party product.

How do I configure GIT to deploy my exit jar?

How do I configure & target different testing, Pre Production and Production environments for GIT to auto deploy to?

All the web examples I can find are linked to deploying war files to the cloud or specific web servers, my use case is to deploy a single jar to a specific server & target folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that git is not tool for building or deploying application.
You should try to find something about CI (continuous integration) servers like Jenkins.

Jenkins can pull changes from specific git repository and run configured job which is responsible for building and deploing.

You can also find something about 'jenkins pipeline'